# looking for a guide to wrap a JavaScript library for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

There are a bunch of great tutorials out there for Angular 2, but this is one that I've not been able to find any information about.  I have an application that uses a specific library which exposes some global variables which developers can access (similar to jQuery), and I need to wrap that cleanly so I an import it like any other library through my `ngModule`.  I've already figured out how to include the library for use, but I'd rather have consistency in how I bring everything in.  This got me thinking, what if I were to wrap the app for Angular 2, what goes into that, and are there any guides showing the process?